# how to kill allien characters in my string?

Tags: c, input, char, output

what i want to do is take a big input(read till users press enter(\n) ) and then call a function that puts the first word of this input(read till ' '). My problem is that even though it looks pretty simple it also has 2 extra allien characters in it. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h> 

void findChoise(char *input, char *choise);

int main()
{
    char choise[12];
    char input[300];
    printf("give me the input: ");
    gets(input);
    printf("%s\n", input);
    printf("%s%d\n", "length of input: ", strlen(input));//for checking
    findChoise(input, choise);
    printf("%s%d\n", "length of output: ", strlen(choise));//for checking
    printf("%s\n", choise);
    return 0;
}

void findChoise(char *input, char *choise)
{
      int i=0;
      while(input[i] != ' ')
      {
          choise[i] = input[i];
          i++;
      };
}
```

Comment: You **do want** to use `fgets()` for safety and `strchr()` for brevity. (Oh, and `const char *` for const correctness, where appropriate.)

Answer (score 2):

What you have already done is very close. You are just missing the null character at the end of the string ("\0"). I have cleaned up your code a little bit and fixed somethings. Please read through it and try and understand what is going on.

**Main things to note:**

1. All strings are arrays of characters and terminates with a null character "\0"
2. When you declare buffers(input and choice), try to make them a power of 2. This has to due with how they are stored in memory
3. Avoid using `gets` and try `scanf` instead

   ```
   #include <cstdio>

   void findChoice(char*, char*);

   int main() {
       char choice[16];
       char input[512];

       scanf("%s", input);
       findChoice(choice, input);
       printf("%s", choice);

       return 0;
   }

   void findChoice(char* input, char* choice) {
       int i = 0;

       while(input[i] != ' ') {
           choice[i] = input[i];
           ++i;
       }
       choice[i] = '\0';
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to write a null character to end the choise string:

```
void findChoise(char *input, char *choise)
{
      int i=0;
      while(input[i] != ' ')
      {
          choise[i] = input[i];
          i++;
      }
      choise[i] = 0;
}
```

also don't use `gets`:

```
fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
```

and use `%zu` to print `size_t`:

```
printf("%s%zu\n", "length of input: ", strlen(input));
```